# RingOut and call log results are not useful (when the call is not answered by a human)

Tags: calllog, ringcentral, ringout

When making a RingOut call between two PSTN phone numbers, RingCentral does not report the call outcome when the callee's phone goes to voicemail or to the "subscriber is unavailable" message or the callee hangs up.

In the cases I have tested the call outcome is always **"Success"** when doing a get request to the RingOut API endoint `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/ringout/###`.

When querying the `call-log` or the `active-calls` endpoint, with the `?view=Detailed` parameter the results is always **"Call connected"** for the whole call and the callee's leg of the call.

My question is how do I determine if the callee's phone:

- Went to Voicemail.
- They hang up.
- They weren't able to answer because of a network issue.

Basically how do I know if a human answered the phone or not?

Comment: FYI, I've started a conversation with our engineering team to determine if/how to identify these states. I'm awaiting a response, and once I've been provided an official answer will share it here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if a call goes to Voicemail, this requires ADM (Answering Machine Detection) which is a functionality of call-center softphone which handles auto-dialing.

RingCentral offers this functionality through the Contact Center product (https://www.ringcentral.com/contact-center/contact-center-features.html). If you need this type of functionality, please contact your RingCentral Account Executive to discuss your needs.

Here is a set of documents which provide greater detail on these deterministic values for RingOut using the API: http://developing-with-ringcentral.readthedocs.io/en/latest/making_calls/#making-a-call